# How do I get rid of "Automatic loading of test framework implementation dependencies has been deprecated"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to build a spring boot application, however I can't get my tests running. It seems like they are failing because of my build.gradle, however after 2 days trying to fix it I thought I might try to ask if anybody here could help.
https://scans.gradle.com/s/m7diapblkqpxk/deprecations

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.fitnessforge'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '20'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.1.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.2.0'
    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.14') {
        exclude group: 'junit'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:6.1.2'
}

tasks.named('bootBuildImage') {
    builder = 'paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testFramework {
        useJUnit()
    }
}
```

UserRepositoryTest:

```
package com.fitnessforge.repository;

import com.fitnessforge.FitnessForgeApplication;
import com.fitnessforge.model.User;
import com.fitnessforge.repository.UserRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@SpringBootTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testSaveUser() {
        // Erstelle einen neuen Benutzer
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("testUser");
        user.setPassword("testPassword");
        user.setRole("Client");

        // Speichere den Benutzer in der Datenbank
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        // Überprüfe, ob der Benutzer korrekt gespeichert wurde
        assertNotNull(savedUser.getId());
        assertEquals("testUser", savedUser.getUsername());
        assertEquals("testPassword", savedUser.getPassword());
        assertEquals("Client", savedUser.getRole());
    }

    
}
```

Changing the build.gradle test part:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I get this:
https://scans.gradle.com/s/c6mdkr55724js

Comment: Your link points to a page that describes the error, gives some info on what to do about it and contains a link to the documentation that explains in detail how to do that. Did you try that; and what's the question you're left with?

Comment: Yes ofcourse I tried that. The question I am left with is stated above. Maybe I missunderstood on how to fix that error, somebody with more knowlege than me can probably tell.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same warning, all I did was add `testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'` to dependencies section.
This has been suggested on github repos of eclipse and gradle [here](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/980#issuecomment-665124002) and [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13955#issue-667688825).